# Telling StructureMap to use another Constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a class with 2 constructors.

MyClass()

and

MyClass(IMyService service)

How do I tell StructureMap then whenever I do a 'new MyClass()' it should actually call the second constructor and not the first constructor.

Please help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you call `new MyClass()`, then StructureMap is not involved at all. No amount of StructureMap configuration will change the behavior.

If you call `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyClass>()`, StructureMap will by default call the constructor with more parameters.

If you want StructureMap to use a different constructor, you can specify the constructor (via PHeiberg's answer):

```
x.SelectConstructor<IMyClass>(() => new MyClass(null));
```

Or you can just tell StructureMap explicitly how to create the instance using the overload of `Use()` that accepts a `Func<>`:

```
x.For<IMyClass>().Use(ctx => new MyClass(ctx.GetInstance<IMyService>()))
```

Comment: What if I want it to use a MyClass constructor that has 2 parameters?  `ctx.GetInstance<>` only permits 1 type parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Joshua's answer is covering all aspects. As a side note in order to configure Structuremap to choose a specific constructor without hardcoding the arguments to the constructor as done in Joshua's example you can use the SelectContructor method:

```
x.SelectConstructor<MyService>(() => new MyService());
```

The lambda in the SelectConstructor method call should invoke the needed constructor (put nulls or any value of the correct type for all parameters present). See [the documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

When using a DI container like structuremap it's best to have just a single constructor on every class. This constructor has to resolve all the dependencies of the class, if `IMyService` is a dependency (which looks a bit strange though) this should always be resolved when instantiating so the parameterless constructor is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected now. Instead of CMyService, I have user CMyClass. Thanks.