# How to tell StructureMap 3 to use specific constructor for specific type?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap, structuremap3

I am using StructureMap (version 3.1.4.143) for general dependency resolution in my Web API project, and it's working fine so far.
I want structuremap to follow it's default behavior of selecting the constructor with most parameters. However, for a specific type I want to use a specific constructor to be used.

e.g. I have some service contract

```
public interface IService 
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

and implementation like

```
public class Service : IService 
{
    public Service() { //something }
    public Service(IRepo repo, ILogger logger) { //something }
    //rest of the logic
}
```

For this type only, I want to use the parameter-less constructor. How do I do that in StructureMap 3 ? (I could do that to all types by creating an instance of IConstructorSelector and applying that as policy like below)

```
x.Policies.ConstructorSelector<ParamLessConstructorSelector>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telling StructureMap to use another Constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998346/telling-structuremap-to-use-another-constructor)

Comment: I don't see that answer working for StructureMap 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

This is the right way to do that in StructureMap 3. With SelectConstructor, structuremap infers the constructor from the given expression.

```
x.ForConcreteType<Service>().Configure.SelectConstructor(() => new Service());
```

Or, it can be specified with For-Use-mapping.

```
x.For<IService>().Use<Service>().SelectConstructor(() => new Service());
```

Check the documentation in Github StructureMap [docs](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/constructor-selection/).

If this rule needs to applied throughout the application, the rule can be applied as a policy by creating an instance of IConstructorSelector

```
public class ParamLessConstructorSelector : IConstructorSelector
{
    public ConstructorInfo Find(Type pluggedType)
    {
        return pluggedType.GetConstructors().First(x => x.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
    }
}
```

and configuring the container.

```
x.Policies.ConstructorSelector<ParamLessConstructorSelector>();
```

Comment: What does the code look like if, for instance, I want to choose a constructor that has 2 parameters?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier `pluggedType.GetConstructors().First(x => x.GetParameters().Count() == 2)` should do. Notice, if you have multiple constructors with 2 parameters, you might need some more logic to specify intended one.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which constructor to use for a specific type. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
x.SelectConstructor<Service>(() => new Service());
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm) for more information.

Edit:

For StructureMap3 it would be:

```
x.Policies.ConstructorSelector(...)
```

Comment: Is it available in StructureMap 3? Under which namespace?

Comment: For StructureMap3 it should be in Policies.ConstructorSelector